# How to link a server.js file with a client.js file using socket.io library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server, socket.io, chat

I'm following a socket.io tutorial to build a simple chat app. I've installed socket.io in the directory with

> npm install socket.io

but nothing is working and I get the error message

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at
> http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NuNNF0D.
> (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status
> code: 200.

This shows on the browser when I inspect the index.html file.
Another error message shows up on localhost:300

> GEThttp://localhost:3000/ [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 7ms]
>
> The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared.
> The document will render with garbled text in some browser
> configurations if the document contains characters from outside the
> US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be
> declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order
> mark as an encoding signature.

```
//server.js
const io = require('socket.io')(3000);

io.on('connection', socket => {
    console.log('new user');
    socket.emit('chat-message', 'hello');
})
```

```js
//script.js
const socket = io('http://localhost:3000');

socket.on('chat-message', data => {
    console.log(data);
})
```

```html
    <script defer src='http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
    <script defer src='script.js'></script>
```

Comment: CORS is your answer: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors. This will allow another server (your socket.io client) to access your server (socket.io server). By the way, in my opinion it's a good idea to keep the client and server on the _same_ server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked

From [the documentation](https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/):

> Since Socket.IO v3, you need to explicitly enable Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).
>
> ```
> const io = require("socket.io")(httpServer, {
>     cors: {    
>         origin: "https://example.com",    
>         methods: ["GET", "POST"] 
>      }
> });
> ```

---

> Another error message shows up on localhost:3000

Well. Yes. The server running on port 3000 is set up to serve up socket.io and **only** socket.io. You've done nothing to tell it do serve up something when the client asks for `/` so it gives you a Not Found error.

Comment: It's so frustrating, I keep getting these outdated info. I took a whole course on d3.js to find out that the version taught in the course was old. Before that, I read a lot about jquery just to find out it was kinda dying, slow and vanilla js is being preferred over it lately. Thanks for the answer.